# exclude one child by id from $post->post_parent

Tags: posts

I'm trying to exclude one child from the children of a parent. What do I need to change here? thanks

```
if ( $post->post_parent == '4426' || in_array( '4426', $post->ancestors) && (!is_page('4430')  ) { // Who We Are
    //do something
}
```

Comment: What's the context here? Are you trying to run the conditional IF you're not on the specific page with the ID `4430`? Are we in a loop here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's just a matter of parentheses.

```
if ( ( $post->post_parent == '4426' || in_array( '4426', $post->ancestors) ) && !is_page(4430)  ) { // Who We Are
    //do something
}
```

I'm assuming `is_page` accepts an Integer being the page ID and `4430` is not the slug or page title.